# How can I expand row width to make the input fields in one row?

Tags: html, bootstrap-5

how can I make the input fields in one single row on a page like this?
These fields are inside a form container.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, look at full page

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="container">
    <div class="p-2">
        Hello World !
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Name" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Device IP" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <select class="form-control">
                <option>Switch</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <select class="form-control">
                <option>LAX59</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <select class="form-control">
                <option>EUR</option>
                <option>ES</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <select class="form-control">
                <option>NET</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```